# on a decomposition lemma in adelic groups

Tags: adeles, algebraic-groups, gr.group-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X a curve over an algebraically closed k.
Fix $x$ and $y$ two distinct closed points of X.
Let G be a connected reductive group over k.

We denote Spec $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$ the formal neighborhood around $x$.

Let $I_{x}\subset G(\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x})$ be the Iwahori subgroup on x.

Let $g\in G(X-y)$. We have in particular that $G(X-y)\subset G(\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x})$

Can we find an element $k\in G(X-x)\cap I_{y}$ such that $kg\in I_{x}$?

Comment: It depends on how you're choosing the Iwahori subgroups $I_x$ and $I_y$. (You say "the" Iwahori, but that's as bad as "the" Borel.) Since $g$ is regular at $x \in X - y$, all elements of $G(k(X))$ lying in $I_xg^{-1}$ (viewed inside $G({\rm{Frac}}(O^{\wedge}_x))$) are regular at $x$. Hence, the hypothetical $k$ is regular at $x$, so it is everywhere regular and hence constant (over the ground field denoted as $k$...).  So $k$ lies in whatever Borel $B_y$ of $G$ "corresponds" to $I_y$ and you're asking if $g(x) \in B_y B_x$. If $B_y$ and $B_x$ are opposite Borels, you win; if equal, you lose...

Comment: Thanks. And for n points is it still true? Say, is there a choice of Iwahoris $I_{x_{1}}$,..., $I_{x_{n}}$ such that :

$\forall (h_{2},....,h_{n})\in G(X-x_{2})\times...\times G(X-x_{n})$ there exists $(l_{2},...,l_{n})$ such that:

(i) $\forall i$, $l_{i}\in G(X-x)\cap I_{x_{i}}$

(ii) l_{2}h_{2}=....=l_{n}h_{n}

(iii)l_{i}h_{i}\in I_{x_{1}} ?


Comment: Correction to the precedent comment in (i)


 And for n points is it still true? Say, is there a choice of Iwahoris $I_{x_{1}}$,..., $I_{x_{n}}$ such that :

$\forall$ $(h_{2},....,h_{n})\in G(X−x_{2})\times...\times G(X−x_{n})$ there exists $(l_{2},...,l_{n})$ such that:
$\\$

(i) $\forall i, l_{i}\in G(X-\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}\cap I_{x_{i}}$ 
$\\$

(ii)$ l_{2}h_{2}=....=l_{n}h_{n}$
$\\$ 

(iii) $l_{i}h_{i}\in I_{x_{1}}$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you should rename your ground field, since you use $k$ later.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure to understand why, in the case where $B_{x}$ and $B_{y}$ are oppposite, $g(x)\in B_{x}B_{y}$?

Comment: Dear prochet: You're right, I was mistaken -- the product of opposite Borels is an open cell and so doesn't work. Probably it never works.  And the fact that one is using a constant point is a sign that this may not be a fruitful thing to consider.  (You never explained the motivation for your question, which might be helpful for suggesting deeper tools to use, like strong approximation, etc.)

Comment: Dear xuhan. For groups, It doesn't work, but actually I need a version of this problem for Lie algebras and your argument works for two points.

So, when I look for n points, can we find suitable Borel so that it works?